# WebSphere PMI - How to find total number of concurrent users?

Tags: performance, servlets, websphere, tivoli

We have a clustered WebSphere environment and have 4 nodes in the cluster. I am trying to find number of concurrent users that use the application. I have turned ON Performance Monitoring Infrastructure (PMI) in WAS for Servlet, JVM and Thread Pool. When I monitor using Tivoli Performance Viewer, I believe I need to look at "LiveCount" under the "Servlet Session Manager". But the count seem to be VERY high, more than what I was expecting (LiveCount shows as 80-100). 
Is this the Metric to look at when trying to find the total number of concurrent users?
Does it keep true login count or is it keeping track of number of sessions?

I was told the underlying application creates only 1 session per login until it gets timeout. At which point, the user will have to login again. So to me concurrent user count = session count = this Servlet Session Live Count.

Can anyone help me here and let me know which metric I should look in PMI to get the concurrent user count? We are are WebSphere 7.x.

I believe I need to count this metric value for all 4 nodes to come up with the total concurrent users.

Comment: I think [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/) would be a better place to ask this.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider **logged on users** vs **concurrent users**, depending what you are really looking for.

The **logged on users** would be successfully authenticated and having valid session in the application, but... they may currently do nothing in your application, or abandoned your application but not logged out.
They will be represented by `LiveCount` - The total number of sessions that are currently live.

The **concurrent users** would be users simultaneously access your application. They will be represented by `ActiveCount` - The total number of sessions that are currently accessed by requests.

And yes, you have to sum this from all your app servers.

See also:
[Servlet session counters](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.iseries.doc/ae/rprf_datacounter6.html?lang=en)

Comment: Thanks for the information. The problem is I see Active Count as 2-4 whereas Live Count is shown as 80-100. That is why I have trouble and doubting if I am looking at the correct counter (Servlet Session Manager related). Also, I used a test environment and I logged into the application using 2 separate users. The LiveCount shows as 2 whereas Active as 0 (even right after Logging in).

Comment: If you have test application and only 2 users, catching them actively accessing the session will be virtually impossible. You would need to use some kind of load tool e.g. jmeter to generate load and many more concurrent request to see something there.